# What is the cleanest way to run my project tests?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I'm working on a PHP/Laravel project and I've written my feature tests but there is a problem in run my tests. My problem is every time that I want to run my tests I should delete all previous tables in MySQL and set back all things that happening after each test. My question is: What is the cleanest way to run my tests each time and after running tests everything back to previous state(before running my tests)? using docker for running tests? or use CI platforms like Github Actions? or you have a better option?

Comment: Aren't there DB reset options by default? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add `use RefreshDatabase;` trait in your test class.
more information at [laravel-doc-test](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test)